# how can we get the value of of VARRAY from IN Parameter in procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I am new to PL/SQL... In Varray how can i get multiple value from IN parameter..... else Is there another ways to get the values...

I want to interate the values through VArray... if any other options then its fine..
coding:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE dynamic_query_build(
    vr_plan_sku_id IN VARCHAR2 )
IS
type plan_sku_id_array IS VARRAY(999) OF VARCHAR2(5000);
plan_sku_id plan_sku_id_array;
total           INTEGER;
vrx_plan_sku_id VARCHAR2(3000);
BEGIN
  vrx_plan_sku_id:= REPLACE(vr_plan_sku_id,',',chr(39)||','||chr(39));
  plan_sku_id    := plan_sku_id_array(chr(39)||vrx_plan_sku_id||chr(39));
  total          := plan_sku_id.count;
  FOR i          IN 1 .. total
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(plan_sku_id(i));
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END dynamic_query_build;
```

Execution:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
vr_plan_sku_id varchar2(200) := '5863314,5863315';
BEGIN
   dynamic_query_build(vr_plan_sku_id);
END;
/
```

My Output:

```
anonymous block completed
'5863314','5863315'
```

Expected output:

```
5863314
5863315
```

now it is considering as single value....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created anonymous block with procedure dynamic_query_build. Added there code, that will split VARCHAR2 variable into varray.
I think, the key to your question is this line - plan_sku_id.EXTEND();
You can extend varray dynamically, but only till it reaches defined maximum (in your case - 999).

```
DECLARE
vr_plan_sku_id varchar2(200) := '5863314,5863315';
PROCEDURE dynamic_query_build(
    vr_plan_sku_id IN VARCHAR2 )
IS
type plan_sku_id_array IS VARRAY(999) OF VARCHAR2(5000);
plan_sku_id plan_sku_id_array;
total           INTEGER;

position PLS_INTEGER := 0;
last_position PLS_INTEGER := 1;
tmp VARCHAR2(5000);
counter PLS_INTEGER := 1;
BEGIN
  plan_sku_id := plan_sku_id_array();
  LOOP
    position := INSTR(vr_plan_sku_id, ',', last_position);
    IF position > 0 THEN
      tmp := SUBSTR(vr_plan_sku_id, last_position, position - last_position);
      last_position := position + 1;
    ELSE
      tmp := SUBSTR(vr_plan_sku_id, last_position);
    END IF;
    plan_sku_id.EXTEND();
    plan_sku_id(counter) := tmp;
    counter := counter + 1;
    EXIT WHEN position = 0 OR counter > 10;
  END LOOP;
  total          := plan_sku_id.count;
  FOR i          IN 1 .. total
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(plan_sku_id(i));
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END dynamic_query_build;
BEGIN
   dynamic_query_build(vr_plan_sku_id);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a replace in the dbms_output statement this will eliminate the quotes from the string

```
     ....
     dbms_output.put_line replace (replace (plan_sku_id(i), '''' ))',',chr(10);
     .....
```

Comment: hi Harshit -- I want the values to use in the array like below.. plan_sku_id := plan_sku_id_array(vr_plan_sku_id);   and i want to iterate the values from Varray

Comment: @user2582602 you are printing the values thats what the above modification will do

Comment: I trying this scenario so i have past the query which i tried... Is it possible to give the inputs for VARRAY in execution time?